# Negation of uniform continuity

Tags: logic, intuition, predicate-logic, uniform-continuity

The definition of uniform continuity is:

Given any $\varepsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0\ \forall x\in I \ \forall y\in I\ \left(\text{if }|x-y|<\delta\text{ then }\ |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon\right)$ where $I=$ the interval on which $f$ is defined

so this means that $\delta$ must remain constant for a given $\epsilon$.

The negation statement is:

$\exists \varepsilon>0\ \forall\delta>0\ \exists x,y \in I\left(\text{if }|x-y|<\delta\text{ and}\ |f(x)-f(y)|\geq\varepsilon\right)$ where $I=$ the interval on which $f$ is defined.

I am trying to understand this logically **without** reverting to rules. The part which I don't understand is $\forall\delta>0$.

Comment: You negated it incorrectly.

Comment: More precisely, the negation of $p\to q$ is not $p\to\neg q$, but $p\land \neg q$.

Comment: I understand why i am not correct but why is $p\to q \equiv p\land \neg q$?

Comment: @usainlightning $\neg (p \to q) \equiv p \wedge \neg q$. Make a truth table:
$$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
p&q&p\to q&p \wedge \neg q \\
\hline
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
1&0&0&1\\
1&1&1&0
\end{array}$$

Comment: I haven't come across truth tables before. I don't understand why say: it is raining $\implies$ sky cloudy is equivalent to (it is not raining) or (the sky is cloudy) (or both)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's first see how we arrive at the *correct* negation using predicate logic and then justify:
$$\neg \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x, y \in I [ |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon] \\
\exists \epsilon > 0 \neg \exists \delta > 0 \forall x,y \in I [ |x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon] \\
\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \delta > 0 \neg \forall x,y \in I [ |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon] \\
\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \delta > 0 \exists x,y \in I \neg [|x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon] \\
\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \delta > 0 \exists x,y \in I [|x-y| < \delta \wedge \neg[|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon]] \\
\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \delta > 0 \exists x,y \in I [|x-y| < \delta \wedge |f(x)-f(y)|\ge\epsilon]$$

What that means: There is some $\epsilon$ such that we can't bound the "change of $f$" around a point $x$ by $\epsilon$, no matter how close we stay to this $x$.
Visualize this with $\tan x$. If $I = (-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi 2)$ points within $\delta$ of $-\frac\pi2$ or $\frac\pi2$ will be "bad" points where the implication $|x-y|<\epsilon \Rightarrow |\tan x - \tan y| < \delta$ fails.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous even though it is not Lipschitz. Indeed nothing will work on a compact domain. You could use $\tan(x)$ on $(0,\pi/2)$, or you could use $x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Also, the tricky thing that is hard to explain in words is that there is a "bad" $\varepsilon$ such that every $\delta$ has a "bad" $x$. But the $x$ can depend on $\delta$, and generally will if $f$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, fixed. (+1)

Comment: Points near $0$ aren't bad either. The problem is just near $\pi/2$. (Perhaps you were thinking of the domain being $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @Ian Yes, I did. Fixing. I'd give you +10 for that :D Feeling stupid.