# Predicate logic inference in a simple proof of uniform continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, predicate-logic

For a function $f$ from a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$, uniform continuity can defined in this way:

$\forall ε>0:\existsδ > 0:\forall p,q\in X:d_{X}(p,q)<δ \rightarrow d_{Y}(f(p),f(q))<ε   $

I want to prove this is equivalent to:

$\forall ε>0:\existsδ > 0:\forall E\subset X:diam\,E<δ \rightarrow diam\,f(E)<ε   $

I have some inference gaps in my reasoning. I will go step by step because I'm new to proving using predicate logic. The outline of the proof ($\rightarrow$ only) is the following:

1. Fix $ε$, and for $\frac{ε}{2}$ I get the corresponding $δ$.
2. Take any $E\subset X$, such that $diam\,E<δ$.
3. If $diam\,E<δ$ then $\forall p,q\in E:d_{X}(p,q)\leq diam\,E<δ$
4. Since $\forall p,q\in X:d_{X}(p,q)<δ \rightarrow d_{Y}(f(p),f(q))<\frac{ε}{2}$
5. Then $\forall p,q\in E:d_{X}(p,q)<δ \rightarrow d_{Y}(f(p),f(q))<\frac{ε}{2}$
6. Then $diam\,f(E)\leq \frac{ε}{2}<ε$
7. Since $E$ was arbitrary, we can generalize $\forall E\subset X$

I don't see how to connect steps 5 and 6. I want to know whether there is a specific inference rule for those steps.

Comment: I mean uniform continuity. Are the quantifiers reversed?

Comment: I think the quantifiers are correct: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122096/negation-of-uniform-continuity

Comment: Wow never mind, I just realized that made no sense at all.

Comment: No problem man.

Comment: Basically you geralize for all p and q

Comment: The diameter of a set is the sup of the distances between points in a set. You need to show that the supremum is less than epsilon. But you are guaranteed that choosing two points with distance less than $\delta$ will ensure that the distance between their mappings is less than $\varepsilon/2$. Thus $\varepsilon/2$ is an upper bound for the distances. Thus $\mathrm{diam}f(E) < \varepsilon/2 < \varepsilon$. Not sure if this answers your question but it provides an explanation for the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find doing proofs this way (especially in analysis) very helpful in understanding the details of what is happening. Here is a complete proof for the forward direction; of course I would shorten in considerably if I were to tun it in as an assignment or just thinking through it for myself.

1. $f: (X, d) \rightarrow (Y, \rho)$ is uniformly continuous
2. $E \subset X$
3. $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \, \exists \delta > 0 \, \forall x, y, \in X \,(d(x, y) < \delta\implies \rho(f(x), f(y))< \varepsilon)$ (by definition).
4. $\exists \delta > 0 \, \forall x, y, \in X \,(d(x, y) < \delta\implies \rho(f(x), f(y))< \frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ (by universal instantation)
5. $\forall x, y, \in X \,(d(x, y) < \delta\implies \rho(f(x), f(y))< \frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ (by existential instantation)
6. $\forall x, y, \in E \,(d(x, y) < \delta\implies \rho(f(x), f(y))< \frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ (by 2)
7. $d(x, y) < \delta\implies \rho(f(x), f(y))< \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ (by universal instantation)
8. $diam(E) = \sup \{d(x, y) : x, y\in E\}$ (defenition)
9. $diam(E) < \delta$ (begin conditional proof)
10. $d(x, y) \leq \sup \{d(x, y) : x, y\in E\}$ (by defenition of supremum)
11. $d(x, y) \leq diam(E)$ (by 8, 10)
12. $d(x, y) <\delta$ (by 9, 11)
13. $\rho(f(x), f(y)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ (by 7 and 12)
14. $\forall x, y \in E (\rho(f(x), f(y)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ (by universal generalization)
15. $\forall f(x), f(y) \in f(E)\, ( \rho(f(x), f(y)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2})$
16. $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ is an upper bound for $\{\rho(f(x), f(y)) : f(x), f(y)\in f(E)\}$ (by defenition of upper bound)
17. $\sup \{\rho(f(x), f(y)) : f(x), f(y)\in f(E)\} \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ (by defenition of supremum)
18. $\frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon$
19. $\sup \{\rho(f(x), f(y)) : f(x), f(y)\in f(E)\} < \varepsilon$ (by 17 and 18)
20. $diam(f(E)) <\varepsilon$ (by 8, 19)
21. $diam(E)<\delta \implies diam(f(E))<\varepsilon$ (9 -20 conditional proof)
22. $ \forall E \subset X \, (diam(E)<\delta \implies diam(f(E))<\varepsilon)$ (by universal generalization)
23. $\exists \delta > 0 \,\forall E \subset X \, (diam(E)<\delta \implies diam(f(E))<\varepsilon)$ (by exestential generalization)
24. $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta > 0 \; \forall E \subset X \;(diam(E)<\delta \implies diam(f(E))<\varepsilon)$ (by universal generalization)

Comment: That's some fine answer, exactly what I was looking for. Just a few comments to see if I get things straigth:
12. is the key because it asserts that the antecedent in 6. is actually true right? The predicate: $∀x,y,∈E(d(x,y)<δ⟹ρ(f(x),f(y))<ε/2)$ does not assure that a pair of points $x,y,∈E$ satisfy $d(x,y)<δ$ right?

Comment: I'll go ahead and try the proof in the other direction:

1. $∀ε>0∃δ>0∀E⊂X(diam(E)<δ⟹diam(f(E))<ε)$

2. $∃δ>0∀E⊂X(diam(E)<δ⟹diam(f(E))<ε)$

3. $∀E⊂X(diam(E)<δ⟹diam(f(E))<ε)$

4. Take any $x,y \in X$ such that $d(x,y)<δ$

5. Define $E={x,y}⟹diam(E)=d(x,y)<δ$

6. By 3. $diam(E)<δ ⟹diam(f(E))<ε)$

7. $ρ(f(x),f(y)=diam(f(E))<ε)$

8. I have the following:$diam(E)=d(x,y)<δ ⟹ρ(f(x),f(y)=diam(f(E))<ε)$

9. Which can be reduced to: $d(x,y)<δ ⟹ρ(f(x),f(y)<ε$

10. $∀x,y,∈X(d(x,y)<δ⟹ρ(f(x),f(y))<ε)$

11. $∃δ>0∀x,y,∈X(d(x,y)<δ⟹ρ(f(x),f(y))<ε)$

12. $∀ε>0∃δ>0∀x,y,∈X(d(x,y)<δ⟹ρ(f(x),f(y))<ε)$

Comment: Yes that is correct.  IF $d(x, y) < \delta$ THEN $\rho (f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$. So if we assume $diam(E)<\delta$, we must show that if x and y are in E, $d(x, y) <\delta$ in order to invoke the  premise.

Comment: As I mentioned, I really do like doing proofs this way to help me understand what is going on, but for the first while I found it highly non trivial. For practice I suggest doing a few baby proofs such as showing sqrt(2) is irrational and the like. But once I got going it really worked miracles on my proof writing skills in general.

Comment: I took a course with Baby Rudin a few years ago, but now I am revisiting it  using predicate logic (which I recently learned by myself) and I found that my understanding has improved. Do you have any good reference for learning predicate logic? Thanks!

Comment: I worked through symbolic logic by copi and worked through the whole book which didn't take all that long. And then I worked through carothers real analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than logical inference to be done in this step.  I think that, in effect, you need the following lemma:

> For all real numbers $r$, if for every $p,q \in E$ we have $d(p,q) \le r$, then $\operatorname{diam}(E) \le r$.

The proof of this lemma essentially involves looking at the definition of $\operatorname{diam}(E)$, which is defined as a certain supremum, and unwinding the definition of "supremum".